# Not able to scrape data from using scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I had used various methods to scrape data from [angel.co](https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=India)

but still unable to scrape data using every time getting an empty list

`results = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".results > div")
for result in results:
    name = result.find_element_by_css_selector(".name")
    print(name.text)`

another one is

`soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        val = soup.findAll('div.name')`

`for post in response.xpath('.//div[@class="base startup"]'):
      item = {}
      item['title'] =post.xpath('.//div[@class="name"]//text()').extract()[0]
      print item`

these are all I had tried if anything else suggested then help me to scrape the page
link to complete spider is 
[here](https://codeshare.io/Gw3nb)

Comment: you are using beautiful soup, selenium and scrapy dude seriously?scrapy and selenium are sufficient

Comment: these are different methods I'm trying you can look at my code link but can't get results from the site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for search results to be loaded and only then extract them:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".startup")))

results = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".results > div")
for result in results:
    name = result.find_element_by_css_selector(".name")
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: I had used the wait too as You suggested in last response. Main problem lies in scraping site isn't giving anything link to spider is https://codeshare.io/Gw3nb